# Querying people with an exact two friends

Tags: postgresql

I have a table as follows.

```
PersonId | FriendId
---------+----------
p1       | f1
p1       | f2
p2       | f1
p2       | f3
p3       | f1
p4       | f1
p4       | f2
```

I need to get all the people (`PersonId`) who have exactly `'f1' AND 'f2'` as friends.

What would be a good SQL statement for this? In the above case, the answer would be:

```
 Person Id
----------
 p1
 p4
```

Comment: If someone has f1, f2 and f5 as friends, should he be in the results or not?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ no they should not

Comment: You should put that in the question then. None of the answers addresses this - probably because the question wasn't clear.

Comment: *"if i am not wrong"*? Did you not test them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the cleanest and most straightforward way is by using `HAVING`.

```
SELECT PersonId
FROM YourTable
WHERE FriendId IN ('f1', 'f2')
GROUP BY PersonId
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Remember that the `COUNT` must match the number of values in `WHERE FriendId IN (...values...)` list, in this case 2.

The `HAVING` clause is similar to the `WHERE` clause, except that it deals with columns after an aggregation, whereas the `WHERE` clause works on columns before an aggregation.

Comment: Maybe clearer. Usually not the fastest though.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be sure, you should check both conditions are true.

> ```
> create table ppl (personId varchar(10), friendId varchar(10));
> insert into ppl values
> ('p1',         'f1'),
> ('p1',         'f2'),
> ('p2',         'f1'),
> ('p2',         'f3'),
> ('p3',         'f1'),
> ('p4',         'f1'),
> ('p4',         'f2');
> ```

> ```
> select distinct personId
> from   ppl ppl1
> where  exists (select 1 
>                from   ppl 
>                where ppl.personId = ppl1.personId 
>                and friendId = 'f1')
> and    exists (select 1 
>                from ppl 
>                where ppl.personId = ppl1.personId 
>                and friendId = 'f2');
> ```
>
> ```
> | personid |
> | :------- |
> | p1       |
> | p4       |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=330572467a933877cd81e864e44ec400)*

There is another question on SO that can help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364969/how-to-filter-sql-results-in-a-has-many-through-relation

Comment: This will return p1 also when he/she has a friend f3: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a8804113983ebfcf3f9134fd54fe3b69